# Is the System.Diagnostics.Stopwatch class normally slow when called repeatedly?

Tags: c#, performance, timer, stopwatch

I have an application which must transmit packets at fixed intervals of 33ms +/- a few milliseconds.

So, I came up with a `SpinTimer` class shown below:

```
class SpinTimer
{
    public void SpinWait(double waitTimeInSeconds)
    {
        if (waitTimeInSeconds < 0.0)
        {
            throw new ArgumentOutOfRangeException("waitTimeInSeconds", "Must be >= 0.0");
        }

        Stopwatch timer = new Stopwatch();
        double elapsed = 0.0;
        timer.Start();
        do
        {
            elapsed = (double)timer.ElapsedTicks / (double)Stopwatch.Frequency;
        } while (elapsed < waitTimeInSeconds);
    }
}
```

However, after profiling the code, I found that the `System.Diagnostics.Stopwatch.GetTimestamp()` call was taking most of the execution time. Just as a note, I can't afford to have the thread sleep and context switch as this causes too much "jitter" in the output rate.

Notes about the profile run:

1. Thread priority was set to `ThreadPriority.Highest`
2. Process priority was set to `ProcessPriorityClass.High`

The original program that I wrote (in C++) accomplished the same effect using the `QueryPerformanceCounter()` and `QueryPerformanceFrequency()` functions. Should I be using these calls with PInvoke instead of the `Stopwatch` class? Or, is there another appropriate way to do this?

Thanks!

Comment: I am confused by the question. You are sitting there in a *tight loop* doing nothing but querying the current time. It should not be a surprise that your performance tests show that you're spending most of your execution time querying the current time!

Comment: I wasn't surprised by it taking time, but how much time... The equivalent C++ code accurately waits (within the frequency spec) the required amount of time. Whereas, the C# code is extremely slow when `SpinWait` is executed vs. not.

Comment: Also see http://stackoverflow.com/questions/795377/what-if-any-is-the-resource-penalty-for-using-system-diagnostics-stopwatch

Answer (score 1, accepted):

After, some more debugging (inspired by Eric Lippert's comment), I realized that my above code was doing exactly as requested. The problem was with the calling code at a higher level of abstraction feeding it extremely long wait times.

Thanks for the suggestions to use `System.Windows.Threading.DispatcherTimer` and `System.Timers.Timer` (I gave both an up-vote); however, after testing each of these, they are limited to ~10 milliseconds of accuracy, which is just not quite good enough for my purposes. But, I did find that my "tight" loop code above is accurate to ~1 microsecond, which is more than enough for my current needs.

An additional resource that others might find helpful is [this](http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/61964/Performance-Tests-Precise-Run-Time-Measurements-wi) CodeProject article about increasing the `Stopwatch` accuracy. The main idea is to essentially reduce the likelihood that your program will endure a context switch, and thus travel through the scheduling queues wasting time.

Answer (score 2):

The stopwatch is in the diagnostics namespace. It shouldn't be used for performance level timing.

you probably want a Timer.

Answer (score 2):

have you tried using a System.Windows.Threading.DispatcherTimer ?

I've created several programs with this, and never experienced any delay at all